# Why won't my JSON array display in a UITableView object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/venues.php"]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", responseArray); // This logs fine
}

@synthesize responseArray;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1; // temporary replacement for return [responseArray count] for testing purposes

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text=[responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

For comparison, the following code does work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.colors= [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Red", @"Yellow", @"Green", @"Blue", @"Purple", nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.colors); // logs fine
}

@synthesize colors;

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.colors count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text=[self.colors objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

**Update**

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` now looks like this, but I'm still not getting any results. Is there a problem with my JSON?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text=[[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
}
```

JSON:

```
[{"name":"venue 1"},{"name":"venue 2"},{"name":"venue 3"}]
```

Comment: in your json array you shoud like this value for key cell.textLabel.text=[responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey@"key"];
And in your view did load also add [table reloadData]; after nslog

Comment: show your response log? I think, you've missed something.

Comment: Nothing escapes from viewDidLoad since everything is assigned to a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @interface YourTableViewController ()<BViewControllerDelegate>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *responseArray;

    @end

    @implementation yourTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      self.responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:0 error:&error];

}

        - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            // Return the number of rows in the section.
            return [self.responseArray count];

        }

        -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            cell.textLabel.text=[[self.responseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"yourKey"];

            return cell;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would you mind taking a look at my edit?